# Does cellForRowAtIndexPath get called multiple times for the same "item"?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have a list of items that represent my data source:

```
self.items = [User]()
for model in self.fetchedItems(20){
    self.items.append(model)
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Let's say that my screen only fits 5 items.
Let's say that the first item in the array (indexPath = 0) is the user `Hannah`.

If the user scrolls all the way down to the bottom, then all the way back up, will `cellForRowAtIndexPath` get called for `Hannah`?

Comment: Try it, see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might, it might not. There is no guarantee one way or the other. One possibility is that the cell that held the `Hannah` object will be returned by the dequeue method for a later index path and then when you scroll back up, the cellForRowAtIndexPath will get called gain for cell 0, and maybe it gets passed the same cell that was passed to cell 5... i.e., it is quite possible that the same cell will be used for multiple rows.

That's why it is so important to set the entire state of the cell when you dequeue it. Possibly using `prepareForReuse` as a helper. It is also why it's important to keep the array state fixed unless you explicitly tell the table view you have changed it (by calling reloadData or begin/end updates.)